# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table

Tags: android

**ISSUE** (LogCat)

> sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table ...
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ....

**CODE**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.v("SQLAdapter","onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+tablename
            +" ("
            +col1+ " TEXT PRIMARY KEY , "
            +col2+ " TEXT , "
            +col3+ " TEXT , "
            +col4+ " TEXT , "
            +col5+ " TEXT , "
            +col6+ " TEXT , "
            +col7+ " TEXT , "
            +col8+ " TEXT "
            +")");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+configTable
            +" ("
            +colName+ " TEXT PRIMARY KEY , "
            +colValue+ " TEXT "
            +")");
    
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(colName, "updated");
    cv.put(colValue, "-1");
    db.insert(configTable, colName, cv);
}
```

**RESULT**

> configTable is being created
>
> tablename is not being created

Comment: Where is the value of `tablename` set? I can't see it in your code. Also, you code never tried to access `tablename`, so what throws the error?

Comment: forget accessing it.. when i get the sqlite file thru ddms ,, i find configTable created but tablename not there

Comment: Did you try to insert something in tablename? You should receive an exception. Would you copy/paste it here?

Comment: 07-21 03:32:23.224: ERROR/Database(11222): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: config: , while compiling: INSERT INTO config(colName, colValue) VALUES(?, ?);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

simply Change Your Databse name in Data base class which you implemented Using   SQliteDatabase

same problem i faced , isolved using same trick.

Comment: I can not test it anymore because I decided not to use SQL in any of my projects. Please if someone tests this and it turns to be wrong, tell me. For now! +1 and tick for you. thank you really

Comment: Happened the same here. I have 3 Classes ("X"DbHelper) inheriting from BaseDBHelper which has the database name. I've done what you mentioned and now it works...

Is very estrange, isn't it???

Comment: @m3n0R very weird. I know I solved this by creating one SQL class for each table! But now am looking at this answer and the feedback. seems he got the right solution.

Comment: It's the solution for me on android 10

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception while testing on a real device. After I added a new table to my database I had to uninstall an older app version from the device . Only then the onCreate() method from the `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass was called again.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Fix the problem by deleting away the old xxx.db created by using the adb command

`adb shell rm /data/data/xxx.db`

Answer (score 0):

"no such table" problem worked out!

When you are using a database.db, Android create also another file named database (without extension) with an android_metadata table.

Finally, I solved just changing 
DB_NAME ="mydb" 
with 
DB_NAME="mydb.db"

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the "no such table" problem. This is no problem from the database or table but from your application.

just you have reinstall our application and everything should be fine.